# Erro na visualização de múltiplos marcadores de Google Maps PHP, JS, HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou a tentar fazer um mapa Google Maps que mostra a localização de um deposíto de lixo, informação que está contida na forma de coordenadas, numa base de dados, e o peso do deposíto, também contido na base de dados.

**Qual o problema para os marcadores não estarem todos no Google Maps?**

Comment: Como você está iterando sobre a lista de marcadores e imprimindo o marcador?

Comment: Estou imprimindo o marcador através da linha `var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('.$users_dumps_map[$dump['container_id']].');`

Comment: Você está imprimindo apenas um marcador.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
echo' <script>

        function myMap() {
            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('.$users_dumps_map[$dump['container_id']].');
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myCenter,
                zoom: 5
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
            var markers = [];';

  foreach ($users_dumps_map as $value) {
    $aux = explode(",", $value);
    echo 'markers.push(
            new google.maps.Marker(
              { position: { lat: ' . $aux[0] . ', lng: ' . $aux[1] . ' } , map: map }
            );
          );';
  }

echo '
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "'.$dump['quantity'].'"
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: `markers` é uma variável do tipo `array` onde eu vou guardar os marcadores. O `push` é um método para adicionar alguma coisa dentro da `array`, no caso estou adicionando as marcações do `google maps`

Comment: Fiz uma alteração no `foreach`, dê uma olhada na alteração e tente novamente.

Comment: a marcação já está ok? só falta os valores, correto?

Answer (score 1):

Você está imprimindo apenas um marcador no mapa, por isso só irá mostrar apenas um.

Cada marcador deve ser um novo objeto `google.maps.Map`. Já que você está imprimindo via PHP, pode iterar os dados via PHP:

```
$latLngList = [
    '40.349859, -8.583798',
    '38.720430, -9.154948',
    '41.159531, -8.659574',
    '40.3497085,-8.5958659'
];

//iteração da lista
foreach($latLngList as $latLng)
{
    echo "var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng($latLng);
    ";

    //criação de cada marcador
    echo "var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng , map: map});
    ";
}
```

Esse é o básico, deve-se iterar sobre cada localização e criar um novo marcador, vinculando ao mapa. Eu omiti o restante de código, pois, ele continuará praticamente o mesmo.

Comment: @TiagoGonçalves Indiferente, isso é apenas um exemplo do que está errado no seu script, corrija a sua realidade.

Comment: Atualizei o exemplo para a forma que você está cadastrando, no mais é só adaptar ao seu código.

Comment: Qual erro? Atualize sua resposta. Além do mais, o código que tu postou no comentário não faz muito sentido.